# JQuery - DatePicker not working in popup forms

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

DatePicker is not working in a popup form, what could I've done wrong?

The form is in a .php format and is triggered by this javascript function below:

---

function popitup_request(url, ar){
     var f = document.forms[0];
     if(ar==""){
     alert("Please choose at least one record.");
     return false;
     }
 
     newwindow=window.open(url, 'name',      'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,
     width=570,height=280');
     if (window.focus) {
          newwindow.focus()
     }
     newwindow.moveTo(screen.availWidth/2-(500/2),screen.availHeight/2-(300/2));
}

---

the form loads but when you click on the icon-trigger nothing happens.
I already tested including the **jquery-1.7.1.js** on both main.php and popup.php.

Comment: No clue what this is. There's no jQuery code anywhere there. Maybe you should post the important parts of the source from main.php AND popup.php. And of course, I'm assuming you've checked your browser's error console?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you bind the Datepicker widget to the form elements in your main view. Since popup is loaded later (on popitup_request), the date fields on that form will not be bound to datepicker.

Include the datepicker js and css only once, in your main view. Add a small javascript to the bottom of your popup form, something along the lines of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("input.date").datepicker();
</script>
```

Btw, your code does not reflect best practices in a number of ways (pixel based layout, magic numbers, mixing native Javascript and jQuery though it's not needed). I'd suggest you go through both a Javascript and a jQuery tutorial to see suggested patterns and good examples for enhancing web pages with Javascript.